# iOS App Crash on view will appear - constraints error?

Tags: ios, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting, constraints, autolayout

i'm facing this weird crash and the log doesn't help me so much.

When i access to my MapViewController application crashes on viewDidAppear and the log shows me some random error.

I'm using the storyboard and the auto layout. On the crash responsable controller i have a fullscreen map (iPad), a bunch of UIbuttons, 4 containers controllers and a popover controller.

I think the error shown is kinda random because the log is not very accurate on interface/storyboard errors but it's only a suggestion.

This bug is driving me crazy, it happens randomly and i can't figure out the reason why. Sometimes the app builds and works perfectly for 20 times in a row and sometimes i always get the error and crash.

some of the errors i get are:

```
error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file
```

or

```
Assertion failed: (scalar != 0), function -[NSISLinearExpression scaleBy:], 
file /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-
993/Layout.subproj/IncrementalSimplex/NSISLinearExpression.m, line 244.
```

or

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
 reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x1f597610> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

or

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f57d480 UIView:0x2003ffa0.trailing == UIView:0x1f579230.trailing>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-05-31 11:12:30.320 RMT Anas Plus[2543:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy    constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
 Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
 (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
 (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, 
 refer to the documentation for the UIView property 
 translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

 (
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x20089640 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x1f579230(748)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f57d480 UIView:0x2003ffa0.trailing == UIView:0x1f579230.trailing>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f57d400 H:|-(944)-[UIView:0x2003ffa0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1f579230 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1f57d480 UIView:0x2003ffa0.trailing == UIView:0x1f579230.trailing>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in    <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

I use a code to programmatically select the initial view controller of my application and bypass the login window if i already have the session file.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController;


tokeN = [[LoginToken alloc]init];

NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/token.json", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]==YES) {

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];


    self.token = [[LoginToken alloc]init];
    self.token = [AnasParsers createToken:data];


    float timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    float expiringDate = [self.token.timeStamp floatValue];

    NSLog(@"now = %f expire = %f",timeStamp,expiringDate);

    if (timeStamp < expiringDate) {

        viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"map"];
    }

    else {

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
        self.token = nil;
        viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
    }
}

else {viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];}


self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions and see what line it crashes on, and post the code in that function and any relevant code that uses it and/or calls it.

Comment: sometimes is here in the app delegate `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]`; sometimes in the main `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RMTAppDelegate class]));
    }
}`
And sometimes on some random memory location...

Comment: XCode shows no errors or warnings.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like an issue with constraints. Are you manipulating the constraints in code anywhere or do they all come from the storyboard? Look in your storyboard and make sure there's nothing dodgy going on with the constraints it automatically adds.

Comment: i've check the constraints in storyboards and they looks ok. I'm not changing them trough code however. It happens that i move containers on runtime, and that's why i use them, i don't know how the storyboard constraints react with the moving. The application crashes only on startup if it crashes. Check the edit i've made in the original post about how i load the storyboard and the controller

Comment: another spot where the compiler get stuck is: `0x3b562960:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr} ` but i really don't know what it means...

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on every line in the function and see between which lines it crashes. That'll give you a direction as to where you should start investigating the issue.